# Can one check formal smoothness using only one-variable Artin rings?

Tags: schemes, ag.algebraic-geometry, smoothness, artin-ring, examples

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes over a field $k$. Can one check that $f$ is [formally smooth](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/more-morphisms.pdf) using only Artin rings of the form $k^{\prime}\left[t\right]/t^{n}$, where $k^{\prime}$ is also a field?

Considering cuspidal curves one can show that you do at least need arbitrarily large $n$.

Comment: Is there more left to do in this question?


Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "using" but I think the answer is no.  X can be nonempty and singular over Y with X(k) empty.

Comment: To check formal smoothness, you have to check that for any square-zero extension of Artin rings A'-->A, and any maps Spec(A)-->X and Spec(A')-->Y (making the obvious diagram commute), there's a compatible map Spec(A')-->X. I think that "using k[t]/t^n" means only checking the cases where A'=k[t]/t^n. If I understood this right, then your answer is correct.